# Xcode JSON string to receive data

Tags: ios, json, string, xcode

Im not sure if Im setting it up right, but I'm trying to receive data on an iPhone app from a server using a JSON string. I have created labels for the string but I don't receive the data. I know the server is working and if I run curl from command line I receive the data. Could someone point me in the right direction.

**ViewController.swift**

import UIKit

class TemperatureWebServer: UIViewController, TemperatureWebServiceDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var currentTempLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lastUpdatedLabel: UILabel!

private var webService = TemperatureWebService()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webService.delegate = self
    webService.startConnection()
}

func temperatureReceived(temperature: String, date: String)
{
    currentTempLabel.text = "\(temperature) °C"
    lastUpdatedLabel.text = "\(date)"
}
```

}

**TemperatureWebServer.swift**

import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol TemperatureWebServiceDelegate: class {func temperatureReceived(temperature: String, date: String)}

class TemperatureWebService: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate
{

weak var delegate: TemperatureWebServiceDelegate?

```
var data = NSMutableData()
var jsonResult: NSArray = []

func startConnection()
{
    let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.0.10/tempjson.php")!
    let request = URLRequest(url:url,cachePolicy:.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,timeoutInterval: 60.0)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request)
    {
        (data,response,error) in
        if (error as NSError?) != nil
        {
            return
        }
        let response = response as! HTTPURLResponse;

        guard (200...299).contains(response.statusCode)

            else
        {
            return
        }
        _ = data!
        }
        .resume()


}

private func connection(connection: URLSessionConfiguration!, didReceiveData data: NSData!)
{
    self.data.append(data as Data)
}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: URLSession!)
{

    getLatestTempReading();
}

func getLatestTempReading()
{
    let dictionary: NSDictionary = jsonResult.lastObject as! NSDictionary
    let tempValue = dictionary.object(forKey: "Temp") as! String
    let dateValue = dictionary.object(forKey: "Date") as! String


    if (delegate != nil)
    {
        if (delegate != nil)
        {
            delegate?.temperatureReceived(temperature: tempValue, date: dateValue)
        }
    }
}
```

}

**AppDelegate**
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, TemperatureWebServiceDelegate {
    func temperatureReceived(temperature: String, date: String) {

```
}


var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

}

Comment: I see no call to `startConnection()`. Also, don't get rid of `NSURLConnection`, prefers `URLSession`.

Comment: Hi Larme, thanks. I added startConnection() to the code above. Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

When you run

```
let webService = TemperatureWebService()
```

you're making a local variable that lives while this function `(viewWillAppear)` is being executed. Once `viewWillAppear` finishes, it will remove the local reference to this variable, which will mean there are no more strong references to it, which means it'll be deallocated. That's why your delegate call is never called and you're not getting your data. Instead, if you make a local variable inside your class `ViewController` like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, TemperatureWebServiceDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var currentTempLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lastUpdatedLabel: UILabel!
    private var webService = TemperatureWebService()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webService.delegate = self
        webService.startConnection()
    }
```

where you made your outlets for your labels. While your `ViewController` class lives in memory, it'll keep a strong reference to your `TemperatureWebService` class. Then you could remove your `viewWillAppear` function all together as well. You're also missing a function call to `startConnection()` like [larme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1801544/larme) mentioned.

Another thing worth mentioning:

```
var delegate: TemperatureWebServiceDelegate?
```

will cause `TemperatureWebService` to keep a strong reference to its delegate. We should mark this property with weak or else we'll have a retain cycle here, where `ViewController` -> `TemperatureWebService` -> `ViewController`, so they'll never be deallocated even if we try to clean up `ViewController`

```
weak var delegate: TemperatureWebServiceDelegate? // to make sure we don't make retain cycles
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your help on this. I tried to add 'weak var delegate. However, the program says I can't add 'weak' to this because it's "non- class bound".

Comment: @00BEAR when you declare you protocol with:
`
protocol TemperatureWebServiceDelegate { 
  func temperatureReceived(temperature: String, date: String) 
}
`
you need to add `:class` after the protocol name so we can make weak references against it.

It should look like:

`
protocol TemperatureWebServiceDelegate: class { 
  func temperatureReceived(temperature: String, date: String) 
}
`

Comment: I did just this. However, I'm still not doing something right. I don't have any errors, but no values in label box either.

Comment: Would this be easy to change from displaying in a label, over to table view? Would this even fix my problem?

Comment: 00BEAR can you make a gist with what you're asking about? I'm not sure I follow what you're asking here.